# Magento Extend Mage_Sales_Model_Order with a new function

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add a new function to Mage_Sales_Model_Order to use it inside  app\design\frontend\mytheme\default\template\sales\order\info.phtml and other places.

I want to show an extra number next to the Order ID.

I tried to extend Mage_Sales_Model in my model xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MY_MODEL>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MY_MODEL>
    </modules>
    <global>
      <models>
        <sales>
          <rewrite>
            <Mage_Sales_Model>MY_MODEL_Sales_Model_Order</Mage_Sales_Model>
          </rewrite>
        </sales>
      </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I already see my model in the Admin Area under the Disable Logging section.

What is wrong in my xml?

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your rewrite should be this instead:

```
<models>
    <sales>
        <rewrite>
            <order>MY_MODEL_Sales_Model_Order</order>
        </rewrite>
    </sales>
</models>
```

This maps to how you would retrieve the model through the `Mage::getModel()` method, e.g:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order');
```